# Function working fine in IE8 but not in Chrome, Mozilla, safari

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am calling this function on event onClick

```
function openGrpLifeStmtReport (busnsourceid,treatyId,policyid,productid,schemename,periodfrom,periodto,plcyeffdtfrom,polcyeffto,benType,exportTo,jasperName,jasperNamesum,reportvar1,reportvar2,reportvar3,reportvar4,userloged,clientId)
{

    document.getElementById("reportvar1").value = document.getElementById("busnsourceid").value;
    document.getElementById("reportvar2").value = document.getElementById("treatyId").value;
    document.getElementById("reportvar4").value = document.getElementById("productid").value;
    var Busnsourceid=document.getElementById(busnsourceid).value;
    var TreatyID=document.getElementById(treatyId).value;
    var PolicyID=document.getElementById(policyid).value;
    var ProductID=document.getElementById(productid).value;
    var SchemeName=document.getElementById(schemename).value;
    var PeriodFrom=document.getElementById(periodfrom).value;
    var PeriodTo=document.getElementById(periodto).value; 
    var plcyeffdtfrom=document.getElementById(plcyeffdtfrom).value;
    var polcyeffto=document.getElementById(polcyeffto).value;
    var BenType=document.getElementById(benType).value;
    var exportTo=document.getElementById(exportTo).value;
    var jasperName=document.getElementById(jasperName).value; 
    var jasperNamesum=document.getElementById(jasperNamesum).value; 
    var userloged=document.getElementById(userloged).value;
    var clientId=document.getElementById(clientId).value;
    var reportvar3; 
    var disorderby = document.getElementById("orderBy").value;
    var disgroupby = document.getElementById("groupBy").value;
            for (var form=0; form < document.forms.length; form++) 
        {
         var what = document.forms[form];
         for (var i=0, j=what.elements.length; i<j; i++) 
         {
           if (what.reportvar3[i].checked == true) 
            {
                reportvar3 = what.reportvar3[i].value;          
                break;  
            }
         } 
        }

        var url = "./GroupLifeAdvRep.do?action=customAction&innerAction=printGrpLifeRep&CedantCode="+Busnsourceid+"&TreatyID="+TreatyID+
            "&Policy Id="+PolicyID+"&ProductID="+ProductID+"&SchemeName="+SchemeName+"&PeriodFrom="+PeriodFrom+"&PeriodTo="+PeriodTo+"&plcyeffdtfrom="+plcyeffdtfrom+"&polcyeffto="+polcyeffto+"&BenType="+BenType+"&exportTo="+exportTo+"&jasperName="+jasperName+"&jasperNamesum="+jasperNamesum+"&reportvar1="+reportvar1+"&reportvar2="+reportvar2+"&reportvar3="+reportvar3+"&reportvar4="+reportvar4+"&disorderby="+disorderby+"&disgroupby="+disgroupby+"&userloged="+userloged+"&clientId="+clientId;
        window.open(url,"target","width=850, height=600, top=75, left=75, toolbar=0, menubar=0, location=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=1");

}
```

the code calling this function

```
<a href="#"><img src="Images/generatereport_btn.gif" alt="generatereport" border="0" onclick="openGrpLifeStmtReport('busnsourceid','treatyId','policyid','productid','schemename','periodfrom','periodto','plcyeffdtfrom','polcyeffto','benType','exportTo','jasperName','jasperNamesum','reportvar1','reportvar2','reportvar3','reportvar4','userloged','clientId')"/></a>
```

Comment: What are the symptoms? One issue is the spaces in the OPEN parameters - they can break stuff in some browsers -
`window.open(url,"_blank","width=850,height=600,top=75,left=75,scrollbars,resizable");`
 others is that IE will allow getElementById on NAMED fields that do not have an ID. Make sure all the fields have an ID

Comment: what do you mean by "not working"? are there any errors in the console? does your computer burst into flames?

Comment: Please show the code that calls the function. Assuming checking the browser console for errors (as suggested by jbabey) doesn't solve it for you.

Comment: ASAP = As soon as I have nothing else to do.

Comment: on clicking on the <img> the new tab should be opened .. and report should be generated, and all this functionality is working perfect for IE* but not for chrome, safari, mozillaFF...

Comment: @nnnnnn i just written that code over here....

Comment: OK, you've added the call, but have you checked the browser console for errors? (In Chrome press ctrl-shift-J to open the console.)

Comment: thanks @nnnnnn your suggestion help me alot... :) and right now i m getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null" at                       document.getElementById("reportvar1").value = document.getElementById("busnsourceid").value;

Comment: That implies that there is no element with the id `"reportvar1"` (or that you are running the JavaScript before the page has loaded).

Comment: @nnnnnn "reportvar1" is initialized in my action class....

Comment: Maybe so, but `document.getElementById()` returns `null` if no element with the specified id exists, so if you're getting the error you quoted on the line you quoted that would mean there is no element with that id.

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks sir... you gave me the great clue....

actually what happened earlier was 

<input type="hidden"  name="reportvar1" />

and now i edited it like

 <input type="hidden" id="reportvar1" name="reportvar1" />

so now i am able to go to the new page... thanks alot sir...

Comment: Cool. Actually the first point of @mplungjan's answer explained why your version without the id (but with name) would've worked in IE but not other browsers.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn - yes, I gave that suggestion in the first comment to this question AND in my answer below.

Comment: @mplungjan thanks sir, for your valuable comments and answer.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

1. IE allows getElementById to be called on fields that have only NAME, no other browsers will allow that, so make sure the form fields have IDs
2. you are calling this onclick of an image inside a link. Not a recommended way. Use onclick of the link and return false
3. Spaces in the OPEN parameters - they can break stuff in some browsers - also `target` may be a reserved word try

:

```
function openGrpLifeStmtReport (busnsourceid,treatyId,policyid,productid,schemename,periodfrom,periodto,plcyeffdtfrom,polcyeffto,benType,exportTo,jasperName,jasperNamesum,reportvar1,reportvar2,reportvar3,reportvar4,userloged,clientId) {

document.getElementById("reportvar1").value = document.getElementById("busnsourceid").value;
document.getElementById("reportvar2").value = document.getElementById("treatyId").value;
document.getElementById("reportvar4").value = document.getElementById("productid").value;
var Busnsourceid=document.getElementById(busnsourceid).value;
var TreatyID=document.getElementById(treatyId).value;
var PolicyID=document.getElementById(policyid).value;
var ProductID=document.getElementById(productid).value;
var SchemeName=document.getElementById(schemename).value;
var PeriodFrom=document.getElementById(periodfrom).value;
var PeriodTo=document.getElementById(periodto).value; 
var plcyeffdtfrom=document.getElementById(plcyeffdtfrom).value;
var polcyeffto=document.getElementById(polcyeffto).value;
var BenType=document.getElementById(benType).value;
var exportTo=document.getElementById(exportTo).value;
var jasperName=document.getElementById(jasperName).value; 
var jasperNamesum=document.getElementById(jasperNamesum).value; 
var userloged=document.getElementById(userloged).value;
var clientId=document.getElementById(clientId).value;
var disorderby = document.getElementById("orderBy").value;
var disgroupby = document.getElementById("groupBy").value;

var reportvar3=""; 
var reportvars = document.getElementsByName("reportvar3");
for (var i=0; i < reportvars.length; i++) {
  if (reportvars[i].checked) {
    reportvar3 = reportvars[i].value;          
    break;  
  } 
}

var url = "./GroupLifeAdvRep.do?action=customAction&innerAction=printGrpLifeRep&CedantCode="+Busnsourceid+"&TreatyID="+TreatyID+
        "&Policy Id="+PolicyID+"&ProductID="+ProductID+"&SchemeName="+SchemeName+"&PeriodFrom="+PeriodFrom+"&PeriodTo="+PeriodTo+"&plcyeffdtfrom="+plcyeffdtfrom+"&polcyeffto="+polcyeffto+"&BenType="+BenType+"&exportTo="+exportTo+"&jasperName="+jasperName+"&jasperNamesum="+jasperNamesum+"&reportvar1="+reportvar1+"&reportvar2="+reportvar2+"&reportvar3="+reportvar3+"&reportvar4="+reportvar4+"&disorderby="+disorderby+"&disgroupby="+disgroupby+"&userloged="+userloged+"&clientId="+clientId;
window.open(url,"_blank","width=850,height=600,top=75,left=75,scrollbars,resiza‌​ble");
return false; // cancel link            
}
```

the code calling this function

```
<a href="#" onclick="return openGrpLifeStmtReport('busnsourceid','treatyId','policyid','productid','schemename','periodfrom','periodto','plcyeffdtfrom','polcyeffto','benType','exportTo','jasperName','jasperNamesum','reportvar1','reportvar2','reportvar3','reportvar4','userloged','clientId')"><img src="Images/generatereport_btn.gif" alt="generatereport" border="0" /></a>
```

Comment: why should i put "_blank" ???? because that field contains my main target which is nothing but my report...

Comment: Call it something else than target then

Comment: @jbabey not working i.e it should go to new tab and generate the regarding report, but its not going to the new tab only...

Comment: Please note that I suggested several times that you must have an ID to use getElementById in other browsers than IE. The target name is not as important, only a suggestion

Comment: yes sir.. now i realize my fault... n thanks again sir @mplungjan